# Angularjs - grunt build - ready for production - Any security concerns

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have been working on a small project in Angularjs. I think its ready to go.

I have been running it with grunt serve. I looked around and found a ton on grunt. I have a few questions.

I typed "grunt build" from the terminal on mac.

It built it (I guess) and copied files into the dist folder of my project.

1. My question is what do I do next?
2. Do I need to min the code more?? I see my scripts are min..
3. Do I just take the Dist folder and copy it to Nginx for deployment
4. I have a Ubuntu server with static ip. I want to test this deployment.
5. Is this ready for production??
6. Any security concerns??

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I have been looking around. Yes, grunt does a lot of the production work for projects.

http://yeoman.io/codelab/prepare-production.html

Grunt server is basically designed to help the developer to run your app, without using an actual server. Apart from serving pages, It does some tasks like compiling sass, less files and reloading the page using live-reload, etc,. whenever you change these files and any additional tasks based on the config you provide in Gruntfile.js

But in a production server, you might expect a lot of traffic and every time files changes recompiling the files and all is lot of mess. I don't think Grunt server can handle the traffic in production and all the tasks, your site may become very slow.

Also Angular is front-end framework, so how do you plan to use any web services with it? To run web services you might be running Apache or node server. so you can deploy your app build in the same server.

You can do all these in your development and you build the app and place it in production site

You can use Grunt Build command to build your angular app and it will give minified javascript, css and other things in dist folder

You can deploy this minified app in your production server. very less code is transfered to the client so you can reduce lot of bandwidth stress on the server and your application will be faster.